# What happens to Ezio's mother in Assassins Creed 2

Tags: assassins-creed-2

When Ezio takes his mother and sister to Villa, he tells his sister that mother "will come back to us". And throughout the game she just sits beside the bed. 
Since I only completed the story missions and glyphs, I wasn't 100% synced. 
Does being 100% synced treats the mother of Ezio? Or collecting all the feathers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you collect all of the feathers your mother will give you the Auditore Cape!... that is the only thing that happens.

Nothing else happens when you complete a 100% synced.

What Ezio's sister may refer to is a trauma from what happened to her.

Comment: Yeah... all that work for a dumb ole cape...

Comment: It really was wildly disappointing. The Auditore Cape merely makes everyone hostile towards you all the time. A bit weak for the time investment if you ask me.

Comment: Thank god I didn't try to get fully synced then...

Comment: Yeah me too. :)

Comment: But if you wear the Auditore cape in all the cities, you get an achievement.

Comment: you also get a hammer

Comment: Big deal. I can snatch an axe or spear from a guard easily let alone a hammer.

Comment: @bronzebeard: the hammer comes when you get 50% of the feathers.